# In WHM, Cpanel is working fine but Website not opening

Tags: hosting, whm

In WHM, C-panel is working fine but Website not opening.
Website continuously loading.

I tried by adding die with message on route index file. But there is no change.
Also enable error reporting and debug mode On.

Thanks In Advance!